# Possibility to add instances of generic types in Java 8

Tags: java, generics

I want to implement some algorithm:

```
public class MaximumSubarrayAlgorithm<TArray extends List<T>, T extends Comparable<T>> 
{

public void DoSmth(TArray simple) {

    T t1 = simple.get(0);
    T t2 = simple.get(1);

    t1 = t1 + t2; // wrong: The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) T, T

    return null;
}
```

}

How to require possibility to add instances of type parameters (and tell it to java compiler)? May be T is not Integer, it may be some other type, that support addition.

Comment: What are you trying to add?  What is 'simple.get()'?  Can you include more information.

Comment: This is impossible since Java doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: defining your own operators doesn't work in java if im not wrong , you'd have to make methods like .add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in Java.  You cannot use + on objects whose types you don't know, except to perform string concatenation; Java does not support operator overloading.

Comment: Workaround? Use concrete types? And rewrite algorithm, for example, for matrices?

Comment: Yeah, use concrete types.  Make your matrix data structure attached specifically to doubles or ints or whatever; don't try to generify it to different number types.